# Sql operator NOT EXIST

Tags: sql

Let's say you have a set of tables like this :

```
Museum(M_name,State) 
Artist(A_name,Country)
Artwork(Id,Title,M_name*,A_name*)
```

I would like to get all the names of museums in California that has no artwork made by da-vinci for instance.

Any explanation on how to do that would help me a lot !

What i've done so far is :

```
    SELECT M_name 
    FROM Museum,Artwork 
    WHERE Artwork.M_name*=Museum.M_name
    AND State="California"
```

But then i'm stuck to exclude museums that contains artworks of a specific author. Some people suggested something like this after last line :

```
    AND A_name NOT EXIST ( SELECT A_name 
                           FROM Artwork 
                           WHERE A_name="Da-vinci")
```

I do understand what that the command EXIST returns 0/1 and depending on the sub-request result, but i can't imagine why it would work in this situation...

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far? Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Your first problem: you have a town column but no state column.  How can you determine whether a museum be in California?

Comment: I'm using mysql

Comment: I'm sorry about that, corrected that mistake

Comment: Is your Museum table called Museum or Musem -- you use both.

Comment: It's all my bad, went too fast when writing , the problem is really simple actually

Comment: Can someone try to solve it with the NOT EXISTS method ?

Comment: @othoSama look at my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Try this method, it uses the NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.name, m.town
FROM Museum m
WHERE State = 'California'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Artwork aw WHERE m.M_name  = aw.M__name AND   A_name = 'Da-vinci')
```

Comment: Looks like the solution i'm looking for

Comment: Do you know how the not exists operator works in this case ?

Comment: For instance if only one museum in california has an aw of da vinci wouldnt not exist return 0 ? And therefore no selection would be done at all

Comment: It checks whether rows are returned in the sub-query based on the WHERE clause. In this example, If a museum has a Da-vinci painting, then that museum will be excluded from the results set.

Comment: @othosama yes, if there are only one museum in California, and it has a da-vinci painting, it will indeed be excluded from the results set, and no results be returned.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a join and a not in

```
select distinct m.name, m.town
from  Artwork aw
inner join Museum m on m.M_name  = aw.M__name
where aw.A_Name not in ( 'da-vinci');
```

Or using !=

```
select distinct m.name, m.town
from  Artwork aw
inner join Museum m on m.M_name  = aw.M__name
where aw.A_Name  !=  'da-vinci';
```

This is with not exist

```
  select distinct m.name, m.town
  from  Artwork aw
  inner join Museum m on m.M_name  = aw.M__name
  WHERE   NOT EXISTS
          (
          SELECT  null 
          FROM   Artwork aw
          WHERE  aw.A_Name  = ( 'da-vinci');
          )
```

Comment: why you don't like not in ?

Comment: I like your solution thanks for the help, but i still need to find a way to write it with NOT EXISTS only

Comment: @OthoSama   . answer  updated  (inefficent ) but based as yoy likeon not exist

Answer (score 0):

Musems with no artwork by Da Vinci

```
SELECT M_name
FROM Artwork
WHERE LOWER(A_Name) NOT IN ('da vinci')
```

You don't say how to find out what state a museum is located.
(now I see your example)

Join to the Museum table to get "town"

```
SELECT M_name
FROM Museum
JOIN (
  SELECT M_name
  FROM Artwork
  WHERE LOWER(A_Name) NOT IN ('da vinci')
) AS X ON X.M_name = M_name
WHERE Town='Calafornia'
```

> The above code is should be the same as the NOT EXISTS() code.  In fact, if you do an explain on both of them it should look the same.

Comment: I'm sorry about the mistake, it was state attribute not town of course

Comment: There is no join needed in this problem

Comment: @OthoSama -- do you want to understand how EXISTS() workds?  EXISTS() works the same way as join.  The server will do the same thing with my code (using join) as with code that includes the work EXISTS().  **THAT WAS THE POINT OF MY ANSWER**

Comment: Yo chill, i would like to solve the problem without the operator NOT IN, that's all

Comment: @OthoSama -- umm...   My answer has a "NOT IN"

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you allready wrote the query in your question:

- I would like to get all the names of museums
- in California
- that has no artwork
- made by da-vinci

---

```
SELECT m.m_name                         -- I would like to get all the names
FROM museum m                           -- of museums
WHERE m.state = 'Californa'             -- in California
AND NOT EXISTS (                        -- that has no
        SELECT * FROM artwork aw        -- artwork
        WHERE aw.m_name = m.m_name         -- For THIS museum
        AND aw.a_name = 'Da-vinci'      -- made by da-vinci
        );
```

Comment: If only one museum in california has an artwork of da vinci wouldnt be the result of the NOT EXISTS be 0 and then the external request wouldnt execute at all ?

Comment: @OthoSama -- it would execute it just would not return any results

Comment: what is `external request ? The `not exists()` excludes rows from the outer query, just like the `WHERE m.m_state = 'Californa'` excludes non-californian rows.  (please note: the subquery is *correlated* )